# Difficult Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

My very weak point is regular expressions and I hope someone can help me.
I have a string:

```
string comment = myOrder[Original Tel Number: Some string that can be any size basically\nHome: 94036\nPostal Code: B4]
```

Now I am trying to break up this string like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match( comment,  @"Original Tel Number:\s(\w+)\s*\nHome:\s(\w+)\s*\nPostal Code:\s(\w+)" );

         if ( match.Success )
            {
                inputOrder.BaseHomeTel = match.Groups[1].Value;
                inputOrder.Home = match.Groups[2].Value;
                inputOrder.PostalCode = match.Groups[3].Value;
            }
```

But it just never seems to match, what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Use an online tester to build your regexes. There are many, I use this: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Tel Number:\s(\w+)\s*\nHome:
```

matches `Tel Number:`, followed by one whitespace character, followed by *one* alphanumeric word, followed by optional whitespace and a newline, then by `Home:`.

Your string contains several words here, which is why the regex fails.

You probably want to allow multiple words:

```
@"Original Tel Number:((?:\s+\w+)+)\s*\nHome:\s(\w+)\s*\nPostal Code:\s(\w+)"
```

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, I've fixed it.Could you look again

Comment: Ok, so what would I need to do, to tell it to take the string till the next word in the Regular expression.Or is it not possible.The string can change, except for Original Tel Number, Home and PosttalCode.They will always be fixed

Comment: @user1702369: It matches in my tests. Are you sure you have an actual newline character in your test string, not a `"\\n"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@"Original Tel Number:\s*([\w\s]+?)\s*Home:\s*([\w\s]+?)\s*Postal Code:\s*([\w\s]+)"
```

Comment: This still doesn't match the string provided by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This will match your string:

```
@"Original Tel Number:(.*?)\nHome:(.*?)\nPostal Code:(.*)"
```

But those \n:s are linebreaks, I assume, which are matched by either \n, \r, or \r\n depending on OS. So try this instead:

```
@"Original Tel Number:(.*?)(?\n|\r|\r\n)Home:(.*?)(?\n|\r|\r\n)Postal Code:(.*)"
```

...Or you can fiddle around with RegexOptions.MultiLine and use $ to match linebreaks.